# What happens during the boot process?

Tags: boot

What happens during the boot process after the Raspberry PI is turned on? I know that it differs from the standard Linux boot process ( [no complex boot manager like Lilo/Grub](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/346/118) ), I also know that the boot process has several steps, the device loads files like loader.bin, bootcode.bin, start.elf, kernel.img... But what is the exact order of these steps?

Comment: There is a boot manager; it is incredibly limited and only loads the files in a predefined order and can only deal with one operating system.

Comment: No boot manager like Lilo or Grub. I've rephrased the question.

Comment: There is a boot loader, called Blob: http://elinux.org/Blob

Comment: as I want to runs something at start, that last step is most interesting to me; when the kernel is started, is it execuiting a sort of script for items which the sysop cares to run st this time? if so, what is it named?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Raspberry Pi boot?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10489/how-does-raspberry-pi-boot)

Comment: This is the older question. Why not mark the other one as duplicate?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As said [here](http://raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=6685) the boot process:

1. GPU Core
2. first stage bootloader, which is stored in ROM on the SoC
3. bootcode.bin ([loader.bin merged](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/commit/1a7fbe8113ffadfde24863f6fcb50ff8be9265c6))
4. start.elf
5. config.txt
6. cmdline.txt
7. kernel.img

After this boot scripts will be called by the kernel:
[systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd) or init

Comment: Additional info: The kernel is then loaded and the rest of the boot process is handled by `init` or `systemd`.

Comment: As of 0ct 05, 2012, `loader.bin` is not used anymore. It was integrated into `bootcode.bin` and removed.

Comment: @KrzysztofAdamski Could please you provide the source so that I can edit it.

Comment: @Haskeller: You mean the source of infrormation? If so, [here's github commit](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/commit/1a7fbe8113ffadfde24863f6fcb50ff8be9265c6)