# How does Raspberry Pi boot?

Tags: boot, kernel

I have a raspberry mini computer and I am wondering how that thing does whole the boot process. I can compile my own kernel and init ramdisk with my own scripts and build my own minimal linux system on PC, but for that I need to use some bootloader. Raspberry doesn't seem to support bootloaders at all.

It seems to somehow boot up using its GPU which reads some partition on SD card (probably that one with bootable flag) that needs to be formatted in FAT32, then it reads some files from there, which are provided, for example by raspbian.

But how would I boot up my own kernel, with my own customizations that I compiled myself? Where should I copy the kernel image / initrd (ram disk) so that raspberry find it and boot from it? I am basically looking for some very detailed technical documentation that describes the boot process on raspberry or just some explanation of this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens during the boot process?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/what-happens-during-the-boot-process)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

From this [Raspberry Pi forum post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=6685) *[Edited to reflect `loader.bin` as an anachronism]*:

> 1. When the Raspberry Pi is first turned on, the ARM core is off, and
>      the GPU core is on. At this point the SDRAM is disabled.
> 2. The GPU starts executing the first stage bootloader, which is stored
>      in ROM on the SoC. The first stage bootloader reads the SD card, and
>      loads the second stage bootloader (`bootcode.bin`) into the L2 cache,
>      and runs it.
> 3. `bootcode.bin` enables SDRAM, and reads the third stage bootloader
>      (loader.bin) from the SD card into RAM, and runs it.  **[ More recent versions do not use a third stage bootloader. ]**
> 4. [ If applicable ]`loader.bin` reads the GPU firmware (`start.elf`).
> 5. `start.elf` reads `config.txt`, `cmdline.txt` and `kernel.img`
>
> `loader.bin` doesn't do much. It can handle `.elf` files, and so is needed
>   to load `start.elf` at the top of memory (ARM uses SDRAM from address
>   zero). There is a plan to add elf loading support to `bootcode.bin`,
>   which would make `loader.bin` unnecessary, but it's a low priority (I
>   guess it might save you 100ms on boot). *[ This change has since taken place. ]*

Here are some resources that could be helpful:

- [Bare-metal programming examples](https://github.com/dwelch67/raspberrypi)
- [Baking Pi Operating Systems Development Tutorials](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/)
- [Raspberry Pi firmware binaries](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware)

Comment: Is that content of these bin files all proprietary software?

Comment: @Petr [Here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware) is the Github for the Raspberry Pi firmware, I'll edit it into my answer.

Comment: also is there any way to make start.elf read an initrd instead of directly booting the kernel? That means, could I create a ram disk which the system boot from, so that I could for example contain my system on entirely different device than SD card (the OS could be living even on some RAID / LVM storage which would need to be initialised first using a script in initrd)

Comment: On the [Raspberry Pi FAQ's](http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs), it says "You have to boot from SD but a USB HD can “take over” after the initial boot. You cannot boot without an SD card."

Comment: Is that parition, which is read first, any partition with B flag or it must be first partition? What if I made it too large and I wanted to create another one on end of SD card which would be smaller

Comment: @Petr You should ask that as another question!

Comment: @Petr proprietary I think. `LICENCE.broadcom` says "This software may only be used for the purposes of developing for, 
  running or using a Raspberry Pi device."

Comment: @syb0rg: Update: it is now possible to boot without an SD card on newer RPis (3+); RPi 1 not at all, only some RPi 2Bs: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/msd.md

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Clear and to the point.