# How does the pi know which kernel to load?

Tags: boot, kernel

In the boot partition there are two kernels, kernel.img and kernel7.img (for the pi 1 vs 2/3). How does the system know which to load?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All the boot magic is in `/boot/config.txt`.

> kernel:
>   The alternative filename on the boot partition to use when loading the kernel; the default value is kernel.img.

from [official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md)

**Update**: to clear up some confusion and to satisfy my curiosity, I tried the following small experiment.

**I DO NOT RECOMMEND YOU TRY THIS!**

1. On my RPi3 I do not have the kernel entry in config.txt, and the system boots up fine.
2. I deleted kernel.img.
3. I renamed kernel7.img to foo.bar.
4. After rebooting the RPi, the system failed to load. I got the [multi-colour screen of death](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Coloured_splash_screen), as expected.
5. I added kernel=foo.bar to my config.txt.
6. Rebooted the system, and it worked.

This proves two things:

1. The system can intelligently select the correct kernel per architecture, within some limits.
2. The kernel entry in config.txt works if used.

Comment: This is **NOT** used by normal images.

Comment: @Milliways What do you consider "normal" in this context? There are several sources, for example this http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/10489/53481 and several things linked from there, that agree with me.

Comment: By "normal" I mean any of the prebuilt images downloadable from the Foundation site. The post you linked is an earlier version of the link in my answer (before loader.bin was removed).

Comment: From the linked docs it seems `/boot/config.txt` is passed as an argument to the closed source GPU firmware `start.elf` which then launches the kernel specified - the confusing bit is that it seems all the boards use the pi 1 kernel image out of the box, but still contain a `kernel7.img` in `/boot` I guess that's what's necessary for one SD card image to work across all the boards.

Comment: @plasticchris: Indeed. Pi 1 doesn't use the kernel7.img at all (and vice versa, Pi 3 doesn't user kernel.img) , but they're both included (with their dependencies). I suspect that it allows for using the same card in various RPi models *automagically*.

Answer (score 2):

See http://elinux.org/RPi_Software#Overview which describes the Pi boot process.

Basically `bootcode.bin` analyses the hardware and (presumably) decides which kernel to load. (The source is not publicly available).

It is (or was) possible to specify a different kernel, but this is **NOT** used by normal images.

NOTE With the new USB/Network boot options for the Pi3 the process has changed but the principle remains similar.

For those interested in reading more about the new boot options [Raspberry Pi boot modes](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/tree/master/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes)

Comment: From your link, I read that completely differently. "Second stage bootloader (bootcode.bin) - This is used to retrieve the GPU firmware from the SD card, program the firmware, then start the GPU." Reading further: "User code - This can be one of any number of binaries. By default, it is the Linux kernel (usually named kernel.img), but it can also be another bootloader (e.g. U-Boot), or a bare-bones application."

Comment: FYI: I tried a small experiment to verify my answer. See my update.

Comment: @SiKing I don't understand why you are deliberately misinterpreting my answer. I said the `kernel` option "is NOT used by normal images" NOT that it couldn't be done. This is easily verified by looking at config.txt in any standard image.

Comment: @SiKing You are also **NOT** answering the actual question "How does the system know which to load" **NOT** what other methods can be used to load kernels.

Comment: I think we are both saying the same thing. I was just trying to clarify my answer. Maybe I failed. Sorry.

Comment: these threads have been very constructive and right on point, IMO. Understanding how these devices work is difficult and general discussion on options and limitations is super helpful.