# How Raspberry Pi booting up?

Tags: pi-3, boot, linux, bootloader, u-boot

I want to know, how Raspberry Pi booting up. Of course, I can google it, but I can`t found this information in official documentation [ https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation ]. I am searching for official detailed info to understand, how it boots.

Comment: See also [What happens during the boot process?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/what-happens-during-the-boot-process)

Comment: @Aurora0001 but where did you get this information?

Comment: You can find the questions I linked by using the search box in the top bar (or, generally more easily, use a site-specific search on Google limited to `site:raspberrypi.stackexchange.com`). The answers there seem to have then got their information from users on the Raspberry Pi forums.

Comment: @Aurora0001 i do not need answers, I want to read primary source

Comment: *I do not need answers* sort of renders a question useless. So what exactly is your point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for "Raspberry Pi boot sequence" will produce https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/bootflow.md

It took me 1 minute to search for it.

Comment: you must have slow internet, I reckon it took about 10 seconds :p